# Difference between oracle database desktop and server class

Tags: oracle, installation

I installed Oracle database 11g enterprise edition to my laptop. When I was installing Oracle, at the beginning I selected Desktop Class (not server class) option.

Now I am trying to make remote connection to my Oracle database from another PC but I cannot connect to Oracle and get this error message:

> "ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist"

even though all Oracle services have been already started.

May the reason be why I installed Oracle as desktop class instead of server class?

My tnsnames.ora file:

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

DERS =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = Ders)
    )
  )
```

Comment: did you try tnsping?

Comment: Can you describe the network topology a bit?  Is your laptop, for example, getting its IP address via DHCP or does it have a static IP address?  On the remote machine, are you using the IP address to connect to the Oracle database?  Or is the remote client using a host name which is resolved by a DNS server?

Answer (score 3):

> *May the reason be why I installed Oracle as desktop class instead of server class?*

No, 'Desktop Class' just means you only get basic choices from the installer<sup>1</sup>, according to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/install.htm#ADMQS12379):

> - **Desktop Class**—This installation class is most appropriate for laptop or desktop computers. It includes a starter database and
>     requires minimal configuration.
> - **Server Class**—This installation class is for servers, such as you would find in a data center, or used to support enterprise-level
>     applications. Choose this installation class if you need access to
>     advanced configuration options.
>
> During a Desktop Class installation, you make only basic choices. For
>   a Server Class installation, you choose either typical installation
>   (where you make only basic choices) or advanced installation.
>
> During a Desktop Class or a typical installation, Oracle Database
>   automatically installs the sample schemas.

You'll need to go through the kind of troubleshooting steps suggested in the comments to find out what is causing the [ORA-12545](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-12545) error:

> An ORA-12545 error occurs when the client is not able to contact the
>   listener on the node specified. For example: when the listener has not
>   been started on the node, if the node address has been specified
>   incorrectly, or a firewall blocks access.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *So 'Desktop Class' and 'Server Class' are poor names for the installation types. 'Basic' and 'Custom' might be better?*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Start with the basics.

- Make sure you have a network connection that is listening on a public IP.
- Then make sure it is reachable. Unless you like totally outdated windows versions your computer has a firewall that will kill all incoming traffic unless told not to.

As per your `tnsnames.ora`....

```
(HOST=localhost)
```

So, the other computer tries to reach a database on `localhost`, which is himself, not your laptop? Now that will not work... per definition. I suggest changing the `tnsnames.ora` file to something sensible.

Answer (score -1):

When installing Oracle Enterprise Database on Windows with `setup.exe` you are asked to choose the systemclass. You have to decide the **systemclass** to be one of these two choices at installation:

1. **Server class**
2. **Desktop class**

When I had to decide, I didn't have further information about the differences of the two possible system classes. As my installation is for Dev-usage on a desktop computer, I supposed Oracle would use this information for resource configuration and decided for (2) Desktop class. That was definitely the wrong choice.

Result: I wasn't able to connect from a client computer to the DB, even though the listener was up, running and correctly configured by `listener.ora`. 
Exactly the situation described in the question.

After endless and desperate research and even a lot more of trial/error measures, I completely uninstalled the DB. After reinstallation with `Systemclass=Serverclass`, the remote access was fine then, immediately.

It's a pity but I didn't find more information about the meaning of Systemclass. Looking back, the option to setup with systemclass=Desktop class seems a bit pointless to me. Even more as I think there is no way to change this once installation is completed.

The problem with systemclass=Desktop class configuration is:

The DB is installed in `localhost::DBname` instead of `MyHostname::DBname`.